# How to sort by custom field value?

Tags: custom-field, sort, rating

I am using these code to sort most Commented, Most viewed Posts

```
<?php $params = $_GET;
unset($params['orderby']);
unset($params['order']);
unset($params['v_orderby']);
unset($params['v_sortby']);
$url = $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
$url = strtok($url, '?');
$url =$url.'?'.http_build_query($params);
?>
 <ul id="sort">
<li <?php if($active == "date"): ?> class="active"<? endif ?>><a href="http://<?php echo   
$url ?>">Most Rated</a></li>
<li <?php if($active == "comment"): ?> class="active"<? endif ?>><a  href="http://<?php   echo $url ?>&orderby=comment_count&order=desc">Most commented </a></li>
<li <?php if($active == "views"): ?> class="active"<? endif ?>><a href="http://<?php echo $url ?>&v_sortby=views&v_orderby=desc">Most viewed </a></li>
</ul>
```

Now I want to sort Custom Field "Rating" as Most Rated 
here is the code of custom field.

```
 <?php
//grab the rating value
$rating = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'rating', true);

//prints star image
for ($i=1; $i<=$rating; $i++){
    echo '<img src="/images/star.png"/>';  
}

//prints unstar image
for ($i=$rating; $i<10; $i++){
    echo '<img src="/images/unstar.png"/>';
}
?>
```

For this I used this code, but it's not working.

```
<a href="http://<?php echo $url ?>&orderby=rating&order=desc">Most Rated</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I understood from your question, you want to sort your result by the most rated custom field `'rating'` which is assumed to be number.
In order to do this you need to write the below `wp_query` argument and to handle it properly in your request. However the end result for your query should be as follows:

```
$args = array(
      'meta_key' => 'rating',
      'order'   =>  'DESC',
      'orderby' => 'meta_value_num'
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply please have a look at http://alturl.com/67pjy i want to sort post via custom field value "rating" you can see there button "most-commented", most recent...